# Sabre RevalidateItinerary: what is the ClassOfService code?

Tags: rest, sabre

I'm using the RevalidateItinerary rest api in my workflow. I'm not clear what the ClassOfService code is in OriginDestinationInformation > TPA_Extension > Flight. Is ClassOfService referring to the bookingCode or cabinCode from the BFM response?

this is snippet from the sample request in DevStudio:

```
"OriginDestinationInformation" : [ {
  "RPH" : "1",
  "DepartureDateTime" : "2017-06-16T11:27:00",
  "OriginLocation" : {
    "LocationCode" : "ATL"
  },
  "DestinationLocation" : {
    "LocationCode" : "BOS"
  },
  "TPA_Extensions" : {
    "Flight" : [ {
      "ClassOfService" : "Y",  //where do I find this code?
      "Number" : 1200,
      "DepartureDateTime" : "2017-11-16T11:27:00",
      "ArrivalDateTime" : "2017-11-16T13:58:00",
      "Type" : "A",
      "OriginLocation" : {
        "LocationCode" : "ATL"
      },
      "DestinationLocation" : {
        "LocationCode" : "BOS"
      },
      "Airline" : {
        "Operating" : "K0",
        "Marketing" : "K0"
      },
      "BookingDateTime" : "2017-09-01T10:03:00"
    } ],
    "SegmentType" : {
      "Code" : "O"
    }
  }
},
...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bookingCode is the same as ClassOfService